# Get a raw disk image from qcow2

Tags: qemu, libvirt, qcow2

I want to install Ubuntu (or any distro) as UEFI with QEMU/libvirt and make some changes there at runtime and shut down the machine. This will create a `qcow2` disk.

If this was not a virtual machine and in the previous step I installed Ubuntu on a real PC instead, I could use a live USB to get access to the hard disk of the PC and do a byte copy of the entire disk. This would leave me with a raw image I could mount on a loopback device or pass it to tools which expect a raw image.

Is there are way to access that kind of raw image directly from qcow2 somehow?

Comment: The linked question has answers showing both how to mount a qcow2 image, and how to convert it to a raw image.

Answer (score 0):

To mount an qcow2 image you can do ...

```
modprobe nbd max_part=16
qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 image.qcow2
mount /dev/nbd0p4 /mnt
```

and vice versa ...

```
umount /mnt
qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
```